# C++ Constructor and vector, iterator

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, iterator, operator-overloading

I am new in c++ and still trying to figure out how things work.
This is my code.

```
Myclass class1("John", "Jones", 1234);
Myclass class2("Michael", "Williams", 2256);
Myclass class3("Robert", "Smith", 3568);

vector<Myclass>vec;
vec.push_back(class1);
vec.push_back(class2);
vec.push_back(class3);

Myclass O1("Michael", "Williams", 2256);
vector<Myclass>::iterator it = find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), O1); //error happens here

if(it == vec.end()){
  cout<<"object found"<<endl;
}else{
  cout<<"object not found"<<endl;
}
```

I want to be able to check if objects of O1 exists in the vector and if it exists, I want it to output "Object exists".

This is my operator overloading

```
friend bool operator==(Myclass& a, Myclass& b)
{
    if(a.name == b.name && a.lastName == b.lastName && a.Id == b.Id)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

output should be:

```
object found
```

Comment: What's your question? Your code looks valid, `it` will either point to the item that it found that was equal, or to `vec.end()` if it didn't find the item..

Comment: You can use `vec.emplace_back("John","Jones",1234);` instead if you never use the `class1`, `class2` and `class3` objects. Additionally, you an replace `if(condition) return true; else return false;` with simply `return condition;`.

Comment: what is a type of `name`?

Comment: It depends on what your `name` and `lasName` members are. If they are `const char*` this won't work (you are comparing addresses).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] along with the relevant error messages (if any). Without knowing all of this, it's highly likely that the problem is your non-const lvalue reference parameters, as the requirements state that you need const lvalue references (or just use normal pass by value, but that is inefficient).

Comment: @hnefatl I just want to be able to check if objects from the constructor O1 exists in the other constructors that are in the vector.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux name and lasname is a type of string.

Comment: @Impuls As Rakete said, provide us with some sample input/output which causes your code to *not* behave like you expect it to. Also, when you say "type string", do you mean `std::string` or `const char *`?

Comment: @Rakete1111 In the line vector<Myclass>::iterator it = find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), O1); I get an error saying "In file included from ----" and I have no idea why, if that is what you're asking.

Comment: @Impuls "in file included from" is just part of the error message. As mentioned before, please create a [mcve] and include the relevant error messages, in full. Thanks!

Comment: "I want to ..." is not a question. It's a statement. At the very least, please rephrase your question with "How do I...". And even then, "How do I output 'Object exists'?" is still not a valid question.

Comment: @hnefatl it is a std::string and I edited how it should be when it works.

Comment: @Impuls Please **copy-paste** entire error message, not just a part of it.

Comment: @Arkadiy My question is why am I getting an error. The program is very simple. I have three constructors, which I put into the vector and I have the fourth constructor that checks if that particular object in any of those three constructors exist, and if they exist the program has to say "Object Found". Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @Impuls The part of the error message you posted isn't actually helpful at all, it's part of most error messages. If you want a solution to your question, you need to give us the **entire message** exactly as given to you by the compiler, otherwise we don't have enough information.

Comment: @hnefatl this is the error, but keep in mind that Proizvod = MyClass

https://pastebin.com/72XBKPjk

Comment: @Impuls Try replacing `Myclass &` with `const Myclass &` in the arguments for your `==` function.

Comment: @hnefatl It is working perfectly now, thank you for your time and suggestion, sorry if you guys didn't understand me at first, english is not my primary language :D

Comment: @Impuls Glad you got it working - just remember to always provide the full error message, and you'll find people will be able to help you much more.

Comment: @hnefatl I will, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [error message you provided](https://pastebin.com/72XBKPjk) it looks like you need to change the arguments of your `operator ==` function from `Myclass &` to `const Myclass &`.